# GET and POST calls fail to load resource

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ipv6, ipv4

In my Ionic application, every `$http POST` or `GET` call gets blocked:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

It works fine in Ipv4 but shows the error when we select Ipv6 in the APNS settings in our phone networks. How should I continue?

Config.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <widget id="com.jio.smart.vehicle" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
      <name>Name</name>
      <description>&#xD;&#xD;
            An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.&#xD;&#xD;
        </description>
      <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">&#xD;&#xD;
          Ionic Framework Team&#xD;&#xD;
        </author>
      <content src="index.html"/>
      <access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
      <access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
      <access origin="cdvfile://*"/>
      <allow-navigation href="*" />
      <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
      <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
      <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
      <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
      <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
      <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
      <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility"/>
      <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
      <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
      <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan"/>
      <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
      <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true"/>
      <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false"/>
      <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="20"/>
      <hook type="before_run" src="hooks/appBeforeBuild.js" />
      <feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
      </feature>
      <platform name="android">
        <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
      </platform>
      <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
    </widget>
```

Comment: Please show me your code .

Comment: @HassanALi which file you want to see ??

Comment: config.xml  and where you are accessing internet . Thanks

Comment: @HassanALi Please see my config.xml file above.Thanks

Comment: Does your mobile carrier support IPv6?

Comment: Yes @MichaelHampton ,i changed the APNs settings of my device from Ipv4 to Ipv6 and after that all my HTTP calls are blocked and showing this error but another apps are working fine

Answer (score 0):

- **Reason Why GET and POST calls are failed ?**

  You had  missed cordova whitelist Plugin.It is required to make GET or POST request.
  **Installation Command**

  cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist

  **Navigation Whitelist**

> Controls which URLs the WebView itself can be navigated to. Applies to
>   top-level navigations only.
>
> Quirks: on Android it also applies to iframes for non-http(s) schemes.
>
> By default, navigations only to file:// URLs, are allowed. To allow
>   others URLs, you must add  tags to your config.xml:

```
 <!-- Allow links to example.com -->
<allow-navigation href="http://example.com/*" />

<!-- Wildcards are allowed for the protocol, as a prefix
     to the host, or as a suffix to the path -->
<allow-navigation href="*://*.example.com/*" />

<!-- A wildcard can be used to whitelist the entire network,
     over HTTP and HTTPS.
     *NOT RECOMMENDED* -->
<allow-navigation href="*" />

<!-- The above is equivalent to these three declarations -->
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="data:*" />
```

For Better understanding Please visit [Official](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/) Documentation

Comment: i already tried this but error no solved ...anything else to do ??

Comment: No its only the issue .Because i haven't seen your cordova whitelist Plugin in your config.xml . If you had tried that then Please update your question . Thanks

Comment: i updated my config file but still the issue is not resolved .